# Linux: export environment variable in a shell script to make it flexible on any server

Tags: linux, export, environment-variables

In order to run a Tcl script on Linux, I need to set the environment variable "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" each time. 
For convenience, I develop a shell script to do this.Currently, on my own server, if I type
`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` 
the result is: 
/opt/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib
so in my shell script I write the following code:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib:$INSTALL_ROOT/tcl_tk/lib64:$INSTALL_ROOT/tcl_tk/lib64"`
where the "$INSTALL_ROOT/tcl_tk/lib64:$INSTALL_ROOT/tcl_tk/lib64" part is what I want to add. It works well. Now the issue is: 
If I want to run the script on any server, so the original "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" will be different, based on my understanding. So how to make it flexible on any server? 
I try this in my shell script: 
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$INSTALL_ROOT/tcl_tk/lib64:$INSTALL_ROOT/tcl_tk/lib64"`

But not so sure,
I am new to system stuffs, need some help. Hope explain the issue clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If your default shell is bash, i would define the variables in ~/.bashrc like:

```
export INSTALL_ROOT=...##assuming a lready defined
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$INSTALL_ROOT/tcl_tk/lib64:$INSTALL_ROOT/tcl_tk/lib64
```

So in this way, you dont have to worry anything about setting variables in multiple shell scripts as this .bashrc is going to setup variable for you beforehand.